# Unable to connec to yahoo URL using Shiny and quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, shiny

When I run the following code, I get the error:

> chartSeries requires an xtsible object

Please advise.

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
ui<-fluidPage(
  ##dialogue box for text data 
  textInput(inputId = "text", label = h3("Text input"), value = "Insert stock symbol"),
  plotOutput("hist")      
  )

server<-function(input,output){

stock<-reactive({getSymbols(input$text)})
output$hist<-renderPlot({chartSeries(stock())})

 }

shinyApp(server=server,ui=ui)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because `getSymbols` does not *return* the data by default. Instead, it assigns the data into the `parent.frame`. Try setting `auto.assign = FALSE` or `env = NULL`.

```
stock <- reactive({getSymbols(input$text, auto.assign = FALSE)})
# or
stock <- reactive({getSymbols(input$text, env = NULL)})
```